# Unique index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to

```
A    B    C
1    a    b
1    b    c
1    e    f
2    d    g
2    x    y
```

But I want a dataframe with values in Column A occuring only once like below

```
A
     B    C
1    a    b
     b    c
     e    f
2    d    g
     x    y
```

I tried to use setting column A as index and also tried groupby. But the dataframe looked same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace duplicated values to empty strings, not possible assign to nothing:

```
df.A = df.A.where(~df.A.duplicated(), '')
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  a  b
1     b  c
2     e  f
3  2  d  g
4     x  y

print (df.A.tolist())
[1, '', '', 2, '']
```

Seems `MultiIndex` should be way, but it only not display repeated values by default:

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
print (df)
     C
A B   
1 a  b
  b  c
  e  f
2 d  g
  x  y
  
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(1, 'a'),
            (1, 'b'),
            (1, 'e'),
            (2, 'd'),
            (2, 'x')],
           names=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply. You seems to have misunderstood, the main requiremnet for me is just to drop the duplicated values only in the column A but retain every rows.

Comment: @cherryblossom - column `A` is `index` ? Or not? what means drop?

Comment: column A is not index, it is just a column. (one way I tried to acheive my result was to set columnA as index, but it didn't work. drop means- I don't want the column value to be repeated, it must be removed only from column A

Comment: @cherryblossom - `don't want the column value to be repeated, it must be removed only from column A` - I think not possible in pandas - only remove rows completely or replace to empty string or to `NaN` - missing values

Comment: Ok, I want it to be replaced into empty string. How can I do it?

Comment: @cherryblossom - Please check solution above, first part.